# Django annotate a static value to queryset

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-queryset

Is it possible to add an static field value to django query set by annotate or any other way?
for example i have an query set called **rooms**. I want all rooms have a static field in query set not in database.
for example:

```
rooms[0].some_field = "static_value"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, you can annotate this with [**`Value`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#value-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import CharField, Value

MyModel.objects.annotate(
    some_field=Value('static_value', output_field=CharField())
)
```

Comment: Is it possible of `some_field` presents on the model?

Comment: @sam: exactly what do you mean? If `some_field` is defined on the model, then no, since that would result in a name clash.

Comment: So, is there any other way to set `static_value ` while querying, to that `some_field `  as we are doing here?

Comment: For newer versions of Django you can just do: 

`MyModel.objects.annotate(
    some_field=Value('static_value', CharField())
)`